# Adding a key-value pair to an object inside loop using React useState hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to add a key-value pair to an object using `useState` inside `map` function. However, the spread operation in `setContainer({...container, [data.pk]: data.name});` seems to be ineffective.

The code snippet below exactly illustrates the problem that I'm trying to solve. In fact, in my original code `container` is declared at another *ContextProvider* component and referenced using `useContext`, but I replaced it with `useState` for simpliticy.

I guess it has to do with the asynchronous nature of `setState` hook, but I don't fully understand what's going on under the hood.

Please let me know what is causing this issue and how to yield the outcome I expected.
Thank you.

```js
const {useState, useEffect} = React;

const myData = [{pk: 1, name:'apple'},
                {pk: 2, name:'banana'},
                {pk: 3, name:'citrus'},
]

const Example = () => {
  const [container, setContainer] = useState({});
  
  useEffect(()=>{
      myData.map(data=>{
        console.log(`During this iteration, a key-value pair (key ${data.pk} and value '${data.name}') should be added to container`);
            setContainer({...container, [data.pk]: data.name});
      })
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>
      <div>result I expected: {"{'1': 'apple', '2': 'banana','3': 'citrus'}"}</div>
      <div>result: {JSON.stringify(container)}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

## Update

The main reason I wanted to use `useState` in loops was to use the state as a container of `refs` of components. However, I found it inefficient to do so, because it caused too many rerenders and was hard to determine when the loop finished. After a lot of searching, I ended up declaring `useRef({})` in the Context Provider and use it as a refs container (which seems to fit the actual purpose it was created I guess). The refs container can be used as following:

```
const refsContainer = useRef({});
```

```
import React from 'react';

const Notes = () => {
    const setRef = (noteId) => (element) => {
        refsContainer.current[noteId] = element
    };
    return (
        <Masonry>                     
            {pubData?.map(publication => {                                                                              
                return <PublicationCard innerRef={setRef(publication.noteId)}/>   
            })}                                                                                                         
        </Masonry>                                                                                                      
    );
};

export default Notes;
```

```
const pubCardRef = refsContainer.current[rank.note.noteId];
window.scrollTo({top: pubCardRef?.offsetTop - 80, behavior: 'smooth'})
```

Comment: take the logic inside setstate out of it and call setstate only once with the new object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what's going on in your component step by step.

1. `container` and `setContainer` are initialized using the `useState` hook
2. the effect in which you map over `myData` is registered, also it will only run once in the entire life of the component because of the empty array `[]` you passed as the second argument
3. the callback you registered in the effect is run. this is what it could look like if you console.log'd the container as well as the key-value pair

```js
(key 1 value 'apple'); container {}
(key 2 value 'banana'); container {}
(key 3 value 'citrus'); container {}
```

> Wait what, shouldn't container be updating on each iteration?

Well yes, but not in the way you expect. The `container` referenced in `useEffect` retains its original `{}` value in each iteration of `myData.map`. What's effectively going on then is

```js
setContainer({ ...{}, 1: 'apple ' }) // RERENDER
setContainer({ ...{}, 2: 'banana' }) // RERENDER
setContainer({ ...{}, 3: 'citrus' }) // RERENDER
```

`citrus` is the final display since it was the last rerender.

Here's a way you can achieve your desired result

```js
const {useState, useEffect} = React;

const myData = [{pk: 1, name:'apple'},
                {pk: 2, name:'banana'},
                {pk: 3, name:'citrus'},
]

const Example = () => {
  const [container, setContainer] = useState({});
  
  useEffect(()=>{
      setContainer(myData.reduce((obj, data) => ({ ...obj, [data.pk]: data.name }), {}))
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>
      <div>result I expected: {"{'1': 'apple', '2': 'banana','3': 'citrus'}"}</div>
      <div>result: {JSON.stringify(container)}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're right, it's because of asynchronous nature of `setState` hook, it basically runs in batch.

From [react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate):

> setState() does not immediately mutate this.state but creates a pending state transition. Accessing this.state after calling this method can potentially return the existing value. There is no guarantee of synchronous operation of calls to setState and calls may be batched for performance gains.

You can create an object first and set it once the loop is completed. Also you shouldn't use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) here. Since you're not creating a new array.

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    const dataObj = {};
    myData.forEach(data => {
      dataObj[data.pk] = data.name;
    });
    setContainer(dataObj);
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const [data,setData]= useState({});
const subData=[{type:'data1'},{type:'data2'}]
     
// expect result for data = {'data1':false,'data1':false}
    
useEffect(()=>{
  setData(subData?.reduce((obj,data) => ({...obj,[data.type]:false }), {}))
},[])
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation to your answer.